# How to restart Jenkins using Ansible and wait for it to come back?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, ansible

I'm trying to restart the Jenkins service using Ansible:

```
- name: Restart Jenkins to make the plugin data available
  service: name=jenkins state=restarted

- name: Wait for Jenkins to restart
  wait_for:
    host=localhost
    port=8080
    delay=20
    timeout=300

- name: Install Jenkins plugins
  command:
    java -jar {{ jenkins_cli_jar }} -s {{ jenkins_dashboard_url }} install-plugin {{ item }}
    creates=/var/lib/jenkins/plugins/{{ item }}.jpi
  with_items: jenkins_plugins
```

But on the first run, the third task throws lots of Java errors including this: `Suppressed: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 503 for URL`, which makes me think the web server (handled entirely by Jenkins) wasn't ready. Sometimes when I go to the Jenkins dashboard using my browser it says that Jenkins isn't ready and that it will reload when it is, and it does, it works fine. But I'm not sure if accessing the page is what starts the server, or what.

So I guess what I need is to curl many times until the http code is 200? Is there any other way?

Either way, how do I do that?

How do you normally restart Jenkins?

Comment: To the one who voted to close this as offtopic: I'm trying to setup a continuous deployment server for my development team with these tools, and the tags already existed. How can you say it's not about programming? Would you think it's fine if I was using Bash instead?

Comment: you can restart Jenkins blind, then use wait_for until it's back up. I have a wait_for_http that is better but haven't done a pull req for it yet.

Comment: @tedder42 There already is a "wait_for" in the code I posted. And the service is already up after the first task. What's not up is the web part, and I don't know how to wait for it. I think I need something like that wait_for_http you mentioned.

Comment: sorry, you're right, you need wait_for_http because the **port** is up even though the *service* isn't. email me and I can give you something to put in your library to beta test. (and yeah, I might put it as an Answer, just need to polish it)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I solved it using curl + Ansible's `until`, which I just learned about. It will request the page until the http status code is 200 OK.

```
- name: Wait untils Jenkins web API is available
  shell: curl --head --silent http://localhost:8080/cli/
  register: result
  until: result.stdout.find("200 OK") != -1
  retries: 12
  delay: 5
```

Answer (score 62):

Using the URI module http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/uri_module.html

```
   - name: "wait for ABC to come up"
     uri:
       url: "http://127.0.0.1:8080/ABC"
       status_code: 200
     register: result
     until: result.status == 200
     retries: 60
     delay: 1
```

Answer (score 4):

I have found that Jenkins always return a 503 response (Service not available) when it's up but not ready. So the most reliable way would be to isolate and examine the response code header alone.

```
- name: Wait until Jenkins web interface is available
  wait_for: "host={{ jenkins_host }} port={{ jenkins_port }} state=present delay=5 timeout=300"

- name: Wait until Jenkins web interface is ready
  command: 'curl -s -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}" http://{{ jenkins_host }}:{{ jenkins_port}}/cli/'
  register: result
  until: 'result.stdout[0] in ["2", "3"]' # 2xx or 3xx status code
  retries: 50
  delay: 3
  changed_when: false
```

Answer (score 2):

Slightly more precise version of @ChocoDeveloper's answer, with this version you can check for a particular response code rather then searching the raw stdout from the HTTP response

```
- name: "wait for ABC to come up"
  shell: "curl --silent -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://127.0.0.1:8080/ABC"
  register: result
  until: result.stdout.find("401") != -1
  retries: 60
  delay: 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help others,  I was trying to achieve similar thing for different service. The issue I had was that `result.find("200 OK") != -1` or `result.status == 200` were not working in my case.

This is what has worked for me:

```
- name: wait for service to boot
  uri:
    url: "https://10.221.54.18"
    status_code: 200
    validate_certs: False
  register: result
  until: result | succeeded
  retries: 8
  delay: 20
```